# Delete nth occurrence of some text in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a big html file in which I have to delete each nth(6th,7th) occurrence of p element, how can I do it in notepad++ using pyscript or regex.

```
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Search > Replace menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   (?:<p>[^<]+<\/p>\r?\n){5}\K(?:<p>[^<]+<\/p>\r?\n){1,2}((?:<p>[^<]+<\/p>\r?\n)*)
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   $1
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press `Replace All`.

You can test it online at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lF0eR1).

Please note that this will delete only the 6th and 7th element of a consecutive list of `<p>` elements. If you want to delete in the same consecutive list the 12th and 13th element, then [Zaheer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20595286/2140859) is right, and you should probably use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use some programming language that read file and delete with a loop or other required logic. As regex in Notepad++ is very poor and if you deleted 6th and 7th occurrence your next 12th and 13th occurrence is now 10th and 11th and further it goes down accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
search : ((?:<p\b(?:[^<]+|<(?!/p>))*</p>(?:[^<]+|<(?!p\b))*){5})<p\b(?:[^<]+|<(?!/p>))*</p>((?:[^<]+|<(?!p\b))*)<p\b(?:[^<]+|<(?!/p>))*</p>
replace: $1$2
```